# Raspberry Pi Robots and custom sensors

Tags: rviz, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am extremely new to ROS, so apologies if this is this years worse question.

I have ROS installed on a Pi, which has a BrickPi shield (drives Lego motors).  ROS works on the Pi as I can see my Neato Lidar data from it (pi is master with Lidar attached)  I used rviz to see the Lidar data.

Aim:  For the Pi to move around an area based on Lidar readings.  The pi is mounted on a LEGO tracked platform (powered by the BrickPi)  This can be controlled via Python

So, am I correct in thinking I need to build a BrickPi Python driver for ROS to use?

Then somehow model the robot in 3D for Rviz to display?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249541/raspberry-pi-robots-and-custom-sensors./) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, I think you've got the gist of it. You would want to create a BrickPi_ROS package that handles the communication between ROS and the BrickPi. Here is an examples of a similar ros driver for a motor controller.

https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/kangaroo_x2_driver

It would probably subscribe to a cmd_vel topic and publish encoder data if there is any

Then you may want to use a mapping package like [gmapping](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ros%20gmapping) to turn your LIDAR data into a occupancy map
And a package like [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl) to figure out where you are in the map
And then finally a package like [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) to navigate around autonomously.

Hope that helps

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2016-12-08**:
Helps? thats freaking awesome mate.   I will let you know how I get on, do you do much ROS yourself?

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-12-08**:
Yes, I use ROS a lot at work :)

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2016-12-30**:
Did you learn off the site or do you recommend anything?